# Fails to catch duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, populate

I'm trying to make a script that 1) Checks if an entry with the given email address already exists in the DB, and if not 2) Populates the DB with a new entry.

This is the code I currently have:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cbsclassy WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) { echo "It seems that you're already participating. It is
only allowed to make one entry into the competition. <a href=index.html>Click to
return to the previous page</a>.";  
}

else { $sql="INSERT INTO cbsclassy (name, email, answer) VALUES
        ('$name','$email','$answer')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
        }

        echo "You're now participating in the contest. The winners will be
        notified        directly via email. Good luck! <a     href=index.html>Click
        to return to the previous page</a>.";
}
```

The script is working fine when it comes to populating the DB, however it doesn't catch if the email address already exists in the DB. Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Please provide some info or a sample of your database structure. Thanks!

Comment: The if-else construct for email check is errate, the echo don't stop the script

Comment: Have you sanitized your inputs (i.e., run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all string inputs)? I doubt the problem is there, but it would help you avoid other issues (like SQL injections).

Comment: As Sam pointed out, there is an error in your if/else code. Yours is if () { }} else { }, when it should be if () { } else { }.

Comment: there are two } } before else?

Comment: I don't know where the two extra } came from, they were not in the code I originally pasted. I tried to remove them, but it still doesn't work. Any other advices?

I'll look into the prepared statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `}`'s before the else so it gets triggered every time.

It'd be more efficient to set a `UNIQUE KEY` on the email field and then check the amount of `affected rows` when inserting to know if it existed or not.

Also as noted in the comments your code is vulnerable to `SQL Injection`. I recommend you use [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

Correct the if/else construct

```
if ($num_rows > 0) { echo "It seems that you're already participating. It is
only allowed to make one entry into the competition. <a href=index.html>Click to
return to the previous page</a>.";  
     } //here remove a }

  else { $sql="INSERT INTO cbsclassy (name, email, answer) VALUES
         ('$name','$email','$answer')";
               if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
             }
           //and also here   
    echo "You're now participating in the contest. The winners will be
       notified        directly via email. Good luck! <a     href=index.html>Click
        to return to the previous page</a>.";
    }
```